# В одномерном массиве заменить последний из нулевых элементов на три нуля

Tags: c++

Необходимо в одномерном (динамическом) массиве заменить последний из нулевых элементов на три нуля. Вот программа, она работает. Правда если в массиве два или более нулей, замена осуществляется с первым нулём, а нужно с последним.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void input(int *a,int n);
void print(int *a,int n);
void insert(int *a,int &n,int &i);
void Poisk(int *a,int n,int &i);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    int *a=new int [n];
    input(a,n);
    Poisk(a,n,i);
    insert(a,n,i);
    print(a,n);
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void input(int *a,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
}

void print(int *a,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<"  ";
}

void Poisk(int *a,int n,int &i)
{
    int j;
    for(j=n;j>-1;j--)
    if(a[j]==0)
            i=j;
}

void insert(int *a,int &n,int &i)
{   int j;int k;
    Poisk(a,n,i);
    for(j=n-1;j>i;j--)
    swap(a[j],a[j+1]);
    ++n;
    a[i+1]=0;
    for(k=n-1;k>i+1;k--)
    swap(a[k],a[k+1]);
    ++n;
    a[i+2]=0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, очень рекомендуется документировать (комментировать) код.

Во-вторых, Вы уже в ф-ции Poisk нашли последний нулевой элемент динамического массива. И записали его в переменную `i` в ф-ции `main`. Кстати, интересно как поведет себя программа, если нулевого элемента в принципе не будет!? Т.о. вызов `Poisk(a,n,i);` в функции `insert` излишний.

В третьих, проверяйте алгоритм работы ф-ции insert - она должна "растянуть" динамический массив на дополнительные два элемента и сдвинуть все элементы за последним нулем в конец массива. Не выделенную явно память использовать нельзя, иначе работа программы будет непредсказуемо. Именно это и получается. Вам необходимо использовать конструкцию вроде:

```
int *a = new int [n]; // выделили память под массив int на n элементов
...
int *b = new int [n + 2];   // выделили память под массив на n+2 элемента
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) // скопируем j элементов
   b[i] = a[i];
...                         // здесь делаем полезные вещи
for (;i < n; i++)           // продолжили копирование
   b[i + 2] = a[i;]
delete a[]; // освободили память из под старого массива
a = b;      // поменяем местами a и b =)
b = NULL;   // b дальше использовать не стоит!
...
delete a[]; // освободили память
```

В четвертых, очень желательно внимательно следить за выделением памяти. Не забывайте, что каждый выделенный блок памяти должен быть освобожден.

В пятых, `system("pause")` - не лучший способ сделать задержку в программе. Попробуйте использовать функцию `getch()` или конструкцию `while (!kbhit())`. Ну, или как вариант можно просто в конец программы добавить какой-либо ввод с клавиатуры =)